# Jetpack Compose: Align a widget in left and right of the parent container in both wrapContent and fillmaxsize state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have one container with 2 Text and the container will be initially in wrapContent and when clicked it will take fillMaxSize with animation. In both cases I want one text in the left and one text in the right.
Basically alignment should be same in expanded and collapsed state. The movement of the text while expanding with animation lineareasing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m26l.png)

```
@Composable
private fun AlignmentWithAnimation() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
        .clickable {
            expanded = !expanded

        }
        .background(Color.Green)

    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .animateContentSize(
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        2000,
                        easing = LinearEasing
                    )
                )
                .let {
                    if (expanded)
                        it.fillMaxSize()
                    else {
                        it.wrapContentSize()
                    }
                }
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)) {

            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .animateContentSize(
                            animationSpec = tween(
                                2000,
                                easing = LinearEasing
                            )
                        )
                        .padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Hello World", color = Color.Red)
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .animateContentSize(
                            animationSpec = tween(
                                2000,
                                easing = LinearEasing
                            )
                        )
                        .padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Hello World", color = Color.Yellow)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this you can use Modifier.weight in the text on the left and Align to position them. Modifier.weight ensures the first text takes up the space and the second text can begin after it, then also to center the texts vertically within their respective boxes you can use .align(Alignment.CenterVertically).

```
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                Text("Hello World", color = Color.Red)
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                Text("Hello World", color = Color.Yellow)
            }
```

Bye